# Why this XML (RSS) fails on IE7/Validator?

Tags: xml, rss

I have this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <atom:link href="http://www.montagnaconamore.it/rss/news.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <title>Adamelloski</title>
        <link>http://www.adamelloski.com/</link>
        <description>eventi del sito adamelloski.com</description>
        <generator>Archimede 1.0 (http://www.archimede.nu/)</generator>
        <language>it-IT</language>
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Corso di Cucina Antiaging]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[<div id="imgOfferta"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.montagnaconamore.it/interne/eventi.aspx?ID=4928&amp;IDE=6350"><img border="0" src="http://www.montagnaconamore.it/images/eventi/Eventi Estate 2011/miniature/corso_cucina_my_vitalis_220x110.jpg" alt="Corso di Cucina Antiaging" class="imgOfferta"></a></div><div id="dataOfferta">Dal 02/10/2011 al 02/12/2011</div><div id="testoofferta">A Folgaria, al My Vitalis Nature Hotel ****, dal 2 ottobre al 2 dicembre, corsi teorici e pratici su un uso bilanciato e rigenerante dei cibi per uno stile di vita salutare antiaging!</div>]]></description>
            <link>http://www.montagnaconamore.it/interne/eventi.aspx?ID=4928&amp;IDE=6350</link>
            <pubDate>Mon, 19 Sep 2011 22:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.montagnaconamore.it/interne/eventi.aspx?ID=4928&amp;IDE=6350</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
</xml>
```

if I try to open on IE7 it fails : "feed contains error".
With [this](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/) validator I get :

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"> 
</xml>
```

What's happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the validator you link to, it just complains about the `</xml>` at the end (you have no `<xml>` and there isn't one in RSS) which makes the document non-well-formed and would use an XML parser to throw an exception.

Comment: @markzzz — Yes, there **is** an end tag but there **is no start tag**. Take it off.